# Amazon SES: Delivery vs SentLast24Hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been using the API to get the total emails I've sent in the last 24 hours.

```
public static double AWS_Quota_SentLast24Hours()
        {
            using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(AllSettings.Default.AWSAccessKey,AllSettings.Default.AWSSecretKey ))
            {
                var sendQuotaResults = client.GetSendQuota();
                return sendQuotaResults.GetSendQuotaResult.SentLast24Hours; 
            }
        }
```

Actually I've sent 50 emails. This can be confirmed with the delivery report in the Amazon SES console: [image]

Is the delivery value available via the API? Why isn't the sent value accurate? I know it takes a while to update, but I've waited a full 20 minutes?

Thanks in advance....